# Frontend communicating with backend using two different domains (internal and external domains)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, network-programming, single-page-application

We are building a SPA application with Vue.js (Frontend). The frontend must communicate with a Java Rest API backend. For this, we have two different domains, one is internal (intranet), and the other is external (internet). I would like to know if there is a good practice or approach for choosing the correct domain.
Our first thought was to do something like the example below when we initialize the frontend:

```
if(window.location.hostname === 'internal.backend.com'){
        GlobalVars.hostnameToUse='internal.backend.com';
}
else {
        GlobalVars.hostnameToUse='external.backend.com';
}
```

Comment: And what's holding you back from implementing it that way?

Comment: Nothing, that was our first thought, but we tried to search for any question similar to this but couldn't find, so we decided to ask. This is the naive approach, we were looking for a different solution or make sure this is a common way to solve this.